# Using Which with a list

Tags: programming, conditional

In a While loop I have:

```
Y1 = Table[A1[[k]], {k, 1, j}];
c1 = Last[Flatten[Position[Y1, 1]]];
a1p[j] = Which[c1 == j, 0, c1 < j, t[j] - t[c1], True, t[j]];
```

I have also same lines for $Y2$, $c2$, $a2p[j]$.

But not always I get correct values for $a1p[j]$ and $a2p[j]$.  It depends on elements of $Y1$ and $Y2$.

For example for sample size $n=5$,

```
t={1.08488,1.30759,1.33781,4.77552,8.36378}

Y1={0,0,0,1,1}, and Y2={1,1,1,0,0}
```

I get

```
a1p= {1.08488,Which[Last[{}]==2,0,c1<j,t[j]-t[c1],True,t[j]],Which[Last[{}]==3,0,
c1<j,t[j]-t[c1],True,t[j]],0,0}

a2p={0,0,0,3.4377,7.02596}
```

Elements of $a2p$ in the above example are correct.

However, since first three elements of $Y1$ are zero, the code cannot find the last element of $Y1$ as $1$.  And I get an error message : {} has zero length and no last element. >>.  The reason that `a1p[1]=1.08488` is correct in this example is that initially for `j=1`, before `While` loop, I have defined `a1p[1]=t[1]` if `Y1[1]=0`, and `a2p[1]=t[1]` if `Y2[1]=0`.  Please note that `Y1[j], Y2[j]` take either `0` or `1`, but they cannot have the same value for a given j.

I also tried

```
a1p[j] = Which[c1 == j, 0, c1 < j, t[j] - t[c1], Y1=ConstantArray[0,j], t[j]];
```

and

```
a1p[j] = Which[c1 == j, 0, c1 < j, t[j] - t[c1], 1\Not[Element] Y1, t[j]];
```

But none of them worked.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: It would be helpful if you included enough code so that one would be able to run your example (you probably only need Y1 and a1p for a minimal example). To make your questions easy for members to answer, a good technique for quality control is to start a new Mathematica notebook and then copy and run your code. If it fails, find the mistake or omission and fix it.

Comment: you probably want `a1p[j_] := Which..`

Comment: ... or perhaps `a1p[[j]]=`? i.e., is `a1p` a list or a function?